# Line chart with regions using c3 angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

I'm creating an angular application where I use [C3-angular-directive](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/) to show my data. Currently I'm showing the data in a basic line chart. From the original data future values are predicted and I want to show these predicted values in the graph by using dotted lines (or similar).

Is it possible to create a [line chart with regions](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_regions.html) using C3 angular directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Angular and C3js library in a professional project.

I haven't tested C3-angular-directive but if you take a look at the site it says :

> The **most used** options of the c3js library are available through the directive as well.

Then I searched in [library itself](https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive/blob/master/c3js-directive.js) and there is no mention of 'region' nowhere in the code, so I don't think this advanced customization is available.

But actually it's very easy to make your own directive with C3js and Angular.

in your JS :

```
.directive('lineChart', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{data:'='},
        link: function(scope, elem){
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: elem[0],
                size: {
                    width:300,
                    height:200
                },
                data: scope.data
            });
        }
    };
});
```

in your HTML :

```
<line-chart data="myData"></line-chart>
```

Here, you can pass data to your chart directive through `data` attribute. Or you can do like them and split data specifying `column-id` attribute etc...

[working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/freezystem/f8a4L8y7/)

**EDIT :** I have updated the directive (in the JSFiddle above) to redraw the chart when data are altered + resolve the tooltip mispositioning.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the library as of now. I will create my own directive. Thank you for your answer and the example of how it can be done.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the tooltip is placed below the chart? It seems to be a problem when using an element directive.

Comment: Actually no. I have created a lot of chart with directives and none of them encountered this bug. I'll try to investigate by my side and will be back to you within a week (I'm on vacation right now with no computer access) if I found something.

Comment: Ok I solved the issue. It was very easy. Just set the display to block on your chart directive. I have also adapted the update algorithm because chart was redesigned for nothing the first time it was displayed ($watch listener is fired when the directive is firstly loaded).